# Straightest way to make desktop App with HTML5 UI in python

Tags: python, html, cross-platform

I have question concerning cross-platform desktop app, I like idea of electron and similar projects, but I have a lot of apps written in python. I would like to make desktop UI in html5 for them. Is there any best straight and viral way to do it? Or we all have to stay in node.js world?
Thank you in advance:)

Comment: What do you mean by "viral way"? Also, are you aware of the multitude of HTML frameworks for python -- flask, django, cherrypy, web.py, etc.?

Comment: By viral I mean most known, famous technique which a lot of developers adopted. Maybe it simply doesn't exist :)